# Finding the most common phrases within a range of cells in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of data that I'm trying to analyse. It hasn't been tagged, so I am trying to set up a way of doing that. Let's say that my list is ice cream shops, the data is something like this:

```
Jack's Akron Ice Creamery
Gerry and Benn's Soft Serve
Macco's Strathfield Ice Creams and Treats
Auburn Ice Cream
Macco's Paddington Ice Creams and Treats
Patterson Ice Creamery
Cold Food Soft Serve of London
Jacks Cleveland Ice Creamery
Mrs Whipper Ice Creams Frankston
Mrs Whipper Frozen Treats Cranbourne
```

What I'd like to do is figure out which of these is the most prevalent in this data set (assuming I can regex and scrub away the punctuation differences).

From the above set, I would hope to surface:

- Jack's
- Macco's
- Mrs Whipper
- Soft Serve
- Ice Creamery
- Ice Creams and Treats

(note, this is a made up list, but I have a similarly random, but grouped list)

I have tried using the `=MODE()` and `=INDEX()` and `=isnumber()` functions with `=sumifs()` and others like these to no avail. I'd assume that the Google Sheets function of `=SPLIT()` would be of value, but the trouble is that I can't use Sheets due to our company policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last sentence makes me think you don’t have the newest version of excel, in which case this answer is pointless, but perhaps it will be useful for someone else. I haven’t come across a great workaround for the inability to use `COUNTIF` in `LET` so it’s a little messy, but it works.

```
=LET(x, TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, $A$2:$A$11),
y, FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(x, " ", "</s><s>")&"</s></t>", "//s"),
z, UNIQUE(y),
p, CONCAT(y),
mycount, (LEN(p)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(p,z,"")))/LEN(z),
mylist, SORT(IF(SEQUENCE(1,2)<2, z, mycount),2,-1),
IF(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(mylist),1)<=5, mylist, ""))
```

The steps are below:

1. Use `LET` to avoid helper columns and make the formula more readable.
2. Join all the cells into a string with `TEXTJOIN` and separate with a space.
3. Use `FILTERXML` to break up the string into individual cells at every instance of a space, and call this vector “y”.
4. Get the unique cells in “y” and call the new vector “z”.
5. Count all the matches of “z” in “y” by getting the difference in length of the whole string and the string minus instances of the word, divided by the length of the word (this is the workaround to `COUNTIF`)
6. Append these matches to the unique vector using `SEQUENCE` (thanks @P.b.!)
7. Sort by the number of matches, and finally elect to show only the top-5 words with the most matches

This gets it in one go, but from a practicality and speed standpoint, I would probably just use steps 2 and 3, paste the unique values, then use `COUNTIF` and delete the unneeded data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Sadly, I'm getting four `#NAME?` cells (2x2) when I placed it.

Comment: Ah `The FILTERXML function is not available in Excel for the web and Excel for Mac`

Comment: Okay, so I now am grasping part of it, but what's happening for me is that it's effectively just grabbing the first five words, listing them on the left, and the right shows up `#VALUE!`

Comment: LET function may not be available (not with our company either). If that's the case, does your version support UNIQUE, SEQUENCE and SORT?

Comment: Figured it out! My list had spaces at the ends, so I just added `=TRIM()` to it all

Comment: @p.b yes, I spun up a windows VM, and made sure the new functions would work. It was my lack of cleansing the data properly by removing trailing spaces in the data that was letting me down. 